# Unknown Seg Fault in C++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I seem to be having an issue with a segmentation fault. I'm not sure why.

```
int inputNumber;
vector<string> inputName;
// Input number of inputs
cout << "Enter the number of inputs you will be using" <<endl;
cin >> inputNumber;
while(floor(inputNumber) != inputNumber) {
    cin >> inputNumber;
}
cout << "Input Number reached" << inputNumber <<endl;


//Enter names of vectors
for(int x=0; x>=inputNumber; x++){
    string temp;
    cout << "Enter the name for input " << x << ": ";
    cin >> temp;
    inputName.append(temp);
    cout << x <<endl;
}
```

The line marked cout << "Input Number reached" << inputNumber << endl; runs just fine. It segmentation faults afterwards. I'm assuming it involves referencing the vector but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: can't see a segfault problem, but your loop condition is wrong: `x>=inputNumber`. You want to loop so long as `x` is _less than_ `inputNumber`: `x < inputNumber`.

Comment: Its odd because if you are entering inputNumber as a positive value you will never go into the for (e.g.  if you entered inputNumber as 5, 0>=5 is false and you'll never iterate).

Comment: `std::vector::append`?  `vector` has no member function `append`, this code wouldn't even compile and, if it did, your loop would likely never execute.  Show us a real example please.  I suppose I am assuming that `inputName` is a `std::vector<T>`, could be wrong.

Comment: Assuming you are using gcc, compile your code with debugging symbols on `-g` and then you can run your program using the debugger `gdb --args ./myapp` and see exactly where it is failing.